# Whats wrong with this HQL query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

did i encounter a hibernate bug or do i have an error i dont see:

```
select enty.number from EntityAliasName enty
  where enty.myId in
  (
    select cons.myId from Consens cons where cons.number in
    (
      select ord.number from Orders ord where ord.customer = :customer 
      and ord.creationDate <
      (
        select max(ord.creationDate) from Orders ord where ord.customer = :customer
      )
    )
  )
```

what i do get is the following:

```
org.hibernate.util.StringHelper.root(StringHelper.java:257)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.util.StringHelper.root(StringHelper.java:257)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1391)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1367)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getIdentityColumn(FromElement.java:320)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolveAsAlias(IdentNode.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolve(IdentNode.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1172)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRefLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5167)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1133)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1993)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1932)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1476)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:580)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:288)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:231)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:394)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
```

using: Hibernate 3.3.2.GA / postgresql

---

**Update:**

i tryed to isloate the error by trying to execute each sub-clause for its own. i figured out that i get the same exception by just executing:

```
select enty.number from EntityAliasName enty
```

but if i execute the following it works:

```
select number from EntityAliasName enty
```

so now the question, **Why?**

maybe i should mention that `EntityAliasName` is an entity alias defined via:

```
<class name="package.EntityName"
         table="entities"
        entity-name="EntityAliasName"
        mutable="false"> ... </class>
```

---

**Update 2:**

I found a solution to the issue. My POJO was mapped this way:

```
<class name="package.EntityName"
             table="entities"
            entity-name="EntityAliasName"
            mutable="false">

  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="val1" column="val1" type="long"/>
    <key-property name="val2" column="val2" type="integer"/>
  </composite-id>

  <property name="id" column="entity_id" type="string" length="255" not-null="true"/>

  ...

</class>
```

there is an issue when having a composite id and using a property named `id`: [HHH-1851](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1851) reported by [Anthony Patricio](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=anthony). Changing the property name from `id` to `entityId` solved the issue:

Thanks to [mdma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326480/mdma) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you calling it with 1 or 2 bind parameters?  It looks like it wants 2, but I am not a hibernate guru.

Comment: there error occurse even without execution, at deployment when hibernate parses static defined HQL's from XML files.

Comment: They are named parameters, so I believe you only need one, since they both have the same name. But to be sure, you could remove the parameters from the query and hard-code values, just for testing.

Comment: The exception seems to indicate hibernate is having trouble with an identity column, myId perhaps? Can you post the entity classes and hibernate mapping file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue. My POJO was mapped this way:

```
<class name="package.EntityName"
             table="entities"
            entity-name="EntityAliasName"
            mutable="false">

  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="val1" column="val1" type="long"/>
    <key-property name="val2" column="val2" type="integer"/>
  </composite-id>

  <property name="id" column="entity_id" type="string" length="255" not-null="true"/>

  ...

</class>
```

there is an issue when having a composite id and using a property named `id`: [HHH-1851](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1851) reported by [Anthony Patricio](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=anthony). Changing the property name from `id` to `entityId` solved the issue:

```
<property name="entityId" column="entity_id" 
type="string" length="255" not-null="true"/>
```

Thanks to [mdma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326480/mdma) for pointing me in the right direction.

just copied the answer from my update above, to close it as answered and keep accept ratio up

Comment: Is this issue fixed in  Hibernate 4 or 5?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting null creating my entityManager like 1-2 hours, no idea why, and this post just solved my problem.

i had in one class (Java):

```
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

I just read your post and changed it to :

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long ide;
    public Long getId() {
        return ide;
    }
```

And finally a good compilation.